# jQuery $.each functioning correctly but yielding TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine the following dataset:

```
{"FakeEconomy":{
"2016-04-05":5651694,
"2016-04-06":5513759,
"2016-04-07":5410169,
"2016-04-08":5094142,
"2016-04-09":4768829,
"2016-04-10":5101458,
"2016-04-11":5776419,
"2016-04-12":5692041,
"2016-04-13":5568383,
"2016-04-14":5555027,
"2016-04-15":5116844,
"2016-04-16":4653882,
"2016-04-17":5112466,
"2016-04-18":5764588
}}
```

When I pass it through the jQuery each function, it works fine, but then it throws a random:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 'visits' of undefined

The following is the jQuery code:

```
console.log(dataset['visits']); // Prints the data above
$.each(dataset['visits'], function(index,value) {
    pageName = index;
    $.each(dataset['visits'][index], function(index,value) {
        timeline.push(index);
        visits_data.push(parseInt(value));
        console.log(timeline);
    })
});
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: Error is not coming from this code. It is coming from somewhere else. Use pause on exception to detect this.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You're a genius. Found out that the reason the program is raising the error was because I placed the jQuery ready function in a js file versus the html file, and because the js file runs faster than the HTML, it shits bricks

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/gvzu13un/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the reason the program is raising an error is because I placed the jQuery ready function, which within it includes the function I wrote above, in the JavaScript file versus the HTML file.

In essence, this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var collected_results = graph_data(dataset); // Has the each function
    var visitsChart = new Chart(collected_results[0], collected_results[1]);
    var devicesChart = new Chart(collected_results[2], collected_results[3]);
    var osChart = new Chart(collected_results[4], collected_results[5]);
})
```

was in the JavaScript file, and the JavaScript file loads faster than the HTML file.

Because the JS file loads faster than the HTML file, it raises the error because it cannot read the objects.